# Django ORM Foreign Key Values how to return as single dictionary

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How do I return all foreign key values into a single dict in the Django ORM?

I understand how to access these values in Python, but I'm looking to retrieve them from a dict, rather than a class.

```
class ChildModel(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField()

class MasterModel(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(ChildModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

- To access the location in Python:

queryset[0].town.location

- Accessing the values themselves does not return the location field.

queryset.values() = {town: 1}

- What I want is:

queryset.values() = {town: 1, location: some_value}

If I run the SQL query in Postgres I get the dict I'm looking for (all inner join fields returned as a single dict). But how to do this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do so using annotation and F, this is a sample code :

```
from django.db.models import F
items = MasterModel.objects.select_related('town').annotate(child_location=F('town__location'))

for item in items:
    print(f"MasterModel: {item.town_id}, Child Location: {item.child_location}")
```

where F helps you reach the value of the child class field.

another way which uses django-rest-framework would be to use serializers which do such thing automatically,

this would be your serializers.py file:

```
class ChildModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = '__all__'

class MasterModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    town_location = serializers.CharField(source='town.location', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MasterModel
        fields = ['id', 'town', 'town_location']
```

and you this code would display the data:

```
data = MasterModel.objects.all()
serializer = MasterModelSerializer(data, many=True)
print(serializer.data[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, that does return the desired data, although it requires me to annotate every single foreign key. Do you know of a cleaner way to do this which doesn't involve manually specifying every field? I was hoping to get all values without explicitly specifying them.

Comment: i edited the answer and added another option which is more convenient especially if you're building an API, but those would be the only methods to do such a thing that I know.

Comment: Incredible! That's exactly what I wanted. Added it to my project and works great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
items = MasterModel.objects.values('town_id', 'town__location')
```

You can also use [alias](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias)